# nameerror when trying to call a function in a class

Tags: python

I was trying to print the index of the values in a string but I keep on running to the error `NameError: name 'findWithException' is not defined` but I defined it right below the class. What is causing this? Any help is appreciated. Thanks in advance.

```
class MyString(str):
    def findWithException(s, c):
        try:
            x = s.index(c)
            print(x)
        except:
            print("Not found")
s = MyString("abcdef")
findWithException(s, "c")
```

Comment: first You have to call it from instance like so : `s.findWithException(s, 'c')` also since it is a class method usually the first argument is self: `def findWithException(self, s, c)` also per PEP 8 function names should be in `snake_case`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess that's what you wanted to acheive:

```
class MyString(str):

    def find_with_exception(self, c):
        try:
            x = self.index(c)
            print(x)
        except:
            print("Not found")


s = MyString("abcdef")
s.find_with_exception("c")
```

**Edit**, after you clarified your issue:

```
def findWithException(s, c):
    if c in s:
        x = s.index(c)
        print(x)
    else:
        print("Not found")
```

That's just what you seem to need.

Comment: I suggest OP also following PEP 8 and naming methods using `snake_case`

Comment: Well, one can see on the first glimpse the OP used to program in C before ...

Comment: I have a test function that checks the code I wrote and it inserts the findWithException it self to call the function it self that's when I run into findWithException is not defined is there a way to call it without the s. in the front? @DevLounge